# Listing of detailed COM port names using VisualStudio 2013 C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to list the active COM ports with detailed names (like in Windows Device Manager). 
I'm using this code and it works, but it is very slow. It can take up to 45 seconds to get a list of 5 COM ports!
Am I doing anything wrong here or is there a faster way to do this?
I know there are several postings about this, but I haven't found the right answer yet.

```
    private void UpdateSerialPorts(RichTextBox _txtBox)
    {

        foreach (string portName in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption LIKE '%{0}%'", portName);
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);
            ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();
            if (coll.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject collObj in coll)
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject obj = collObj;
                    _txtBox.AppendText(portName + " " + obj.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString() + "\r\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _txtBox.AppendText(new SerialPort(portName).ToString() + "\r\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmya, 45 sec is a network timeout.  That happens when you iterate *everything*, do consider limiting the scope by only querying Win32_SerialPort.

Comment: That is faster, but it only returns the details name for the first port. The rest is just shown as "System.IO.Ports.SerialPort"